# Return group results in Cypher query (using apoc)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am able to count nodes by property using apoc, with this query

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(['Package'],['Repository'])
yield nodes
return nodes
```

I can see that the `Repository` field is returned with a `_count` property

Now I'd like to return just those two properties in my query, but I don't see how ...

I've tried

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(['Package'],['Repository'])
yield nodes
return nodes.Repository, nodes._count;
```

but I get

```
Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node or Relationship but was List<Node> (line 3, column 8 
(offset: 77))
"return nodes.Repository, nodes._count;"
            ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `apoc.nodes.group` procedure is not a single node but a list of nodes, as you can see in the error message.

You can just unwind them and return the result :

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(['Package'],['Repository'])
YIELD nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
RETURN node.Repository, node._count;
```